# Adding a button in UITabBar to trigger a popover

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am building an iPad app which basically has a UITabController which controls and displays 2 UIViewControllers that I set via:

```
[tabBarController setViewControllers:
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:browserController, videoController, nil]];
```

I would like to add a 3rd button to the UITabBar that presents a Popover when clicking it. 
I have no idea how to do this...

I tried a couple of things like:
(in .h)

```
UITabBarItem *bbiOpenPopOver;
```

(in .m)

```
[bbiOpenPopOver setTitle:@"test"];
tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = bbiOpenPopOver;
```

But I guess I was way off, this did nothing visible...

How can I add an item to a UITabBar by code, that will present a Popover?

Thank you for any feedback and/or pointers.

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UITabBarItem` should not display a popover. The [Apple HIGs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/index.html) specifically state that they should be used to switch view, and should not be used to invoke code.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but hey, I'll take it. I ended up going heads up display style...

Comment: Even though the HIG says this, a bunch of apps do it unfortunately. Instagram, various shopping apps, etc. They all want a middle button to do an action.

Comment: I don't think the OP was asking your opinion. I think she had an interest in how this is done.

Comment: It's unfortunate that answers that point out Apple policy get down-voted.

Comment: -1 for quoting HIG without telling version and page. I'm looking into 2012-12-17 (circa iOS 6), pages 131-133 (Tab Bar Usage Guidelines), and there's no mentioning of using tab bar to present popovers.

Comment: Well it's obviously not the 2012 one since I posted that on 24/6/10

Answer (score 6):

You can set the delegate of the `UITabController` and then implement the function `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` like this:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (viewController == myDummyVC )
    {
        //show popup

        return NO; //does not change the tab
    }

    return YES; //does change the tab
}
```

This way you will show the popup instead of changing the view and selecting the tab.